# Usage behind the pound symbol in XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

What purpose is the symbol # in XML documents (see sample below)? Are these # symbol to indicate reference to another node, where I am to remove the # symbol prior to searching the nodes for this matching attribute text? Or are these used for jumping to memory addressed nodes somehow, after the XML document was parsed, and this being the reference for the parser?

`Sample XML:`

```
    <vertices id="Plane_003-mesh-vertices">
      <input semantic="POSITION" source="#Plane_003-mesh-positions"/>
    </vertices>
    <polylist count="2">
      <input semantic="VERTEX" source="#Plane_003-mesh-vertices" offset="0"/>
      <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#Plane_003-mesh-normals" offset="1"/>
      <vcount>3 3 </vcount>
      <p>0 0 3 0 2 0 0 1 2 1 1 1</p>
    </polylist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends wholly on the XML language. By itself, the pound has no special meaning in XML. (Remember, XML is a "meta-language", that is, basically a language construction kit.) But when an XML language, e.g., XHTML, decides to put meaning behind it, it can do so.

In your case, it looks like the XML language in question decided to have `id` attributes and `source` attributes linking to them via "URL fragment identifiers."

Comment: Would you happen to know if rapidxml-1.13+ has any search method which could utilize this "URL fragment identifiers", or do I need to do the search for it manually?

Comment: From a quick glance, RapidXML seems to be an XML parser only. That is, it has no in-depth knowledge of the specific XML language it parses. So my guess is, that it's up to you to search. If you can pipe the XML into anything, that creates a DOM, you could use `document.getElementById(substring(id, 1))` to get the element in question. (DOMs are not necessarily HTML-only.)

Comment: Thank you... I checked the documentation also, finding noting either... I have done the search process maually, and it's working great...